# Github merge conflict

Tags: git, github, git-merge

I'm having problems with my github for a project I'm currently doing.
This is the error I'm getting when dealing with the pull request.

[image: first screenshot]

I think I have accidently got all the files on my machine when dealing with the one persons branch, it says I'm 26 Uncommits on my changes on the master.

[image: 2nd screenshot]

If I just sync it straight to the master will github pick up the code was his? cause I don't want to take credit for somebody else's work.

Comment: It says right under the "This branch has conflicts" message that: _"Use the command line to resolve conflicts before continuing"_, and even contains a link to some more instructions.

Answer (score 0):

You SHOULD NOT commit these file into git repos.

Now please delete them with `--cache`.
And add it to gitignore.
Then commit.

Example:
`git rm --cached wil/wil.v12.suo`

If you keep it in your repo, you will see conflict almost every time.